# Good books that give a detailed explanation of different topics in philosophy

Tags: reference-request

So, I couldn't really find any resources on this online, so I am looking for recommendations. What I am looking for is a philosophy book meant for somewhere around moderately experienced readers, sorted topic wise, in the format of taking up a particular topic, say something like Moral Realism, discussing a few variations/schools of thought in that field, and the interpretations or actual texts of philosophers representing their view on that topic, and then moving onto the next, related/similar topic. The problem with most introductory texts to philosophy is that they are either categorised history-wise, starting from the Greeks, or philosopher-wise, taking one philosopher, explaining what he/she is best known for, and moving on, completing a pile of not-too-much in depth, but a finished overview, of different philosophers. Also, books that inculcate Eastern/African/any other non-Western philosophy would also be an additional bonus. Not looking for philosophical puzzle/challenge books, but those that delve into schools of thought, isms, etc. and give detailed arguments for and against them.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On-line, you can see [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/) as well as [IEP](https://www.iep.utm.edu/).

Comment: I tried IEP, it is a bit too advanced, as well as the fact that there is no useful chronological order. For instance, a particular page links to multiple other pages, etc. and in order to understand one, you need to understand quite a lot more, so I can't find any beginning point. Alphabetical order doesn't seem to help me here. :-(

Comment: For a topic-oriented book: Duncan Pritchard (editor), [What is this thing called Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=7YD_CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Routledge (2015)

Comment: Also Neil Tennant, [Introducing Philosophy : God Mind World and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=VbagBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2015) and Simon Blackburn, [Think : A Compelling Introduction to Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=yEEITQSyxAMC&printsec=frontcover), Oxford UP (1999).

Answer (score -2):

The Analects by Confucius.
To understand it is really by taking the time to understand. Morality is that it's self anyways.